# outlook : not receiving mails from other clients

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

I have MS outlook 2010 configured for my office mails. We had recently shifted our office. After restoring the connection i see that i am not receiving any mails from other mail clients like gmail. I am able to send mails successfully to any mail ids but receiving mails only from our office mail ids not from other mail ids.

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth checking your smtp address in Exchange hasn't been changed as this should be the only difference between routing for internal and external emails